# Machine parseable error messages

Tags: bazel

(From https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bazel-discuss/cIBIP-Oyzzw/caesbhdEAAAJ)

What is the recommended way for rules to export information about failures such that downstream tools can include them in UIs.

Example use case:
I ran `bazel test //my:target`, and one of the actions for `//my:target` fails because there is an unknown variable "usrname" in `my/target.foo` at line 7 column 10. It would also like to report that "username" is a valid variable and this is a possible misspelling. And thus wants to suggest an addition of an "e" character.

One way I have thought to do this is to have a separate file that my action produces `//my:target.errors` that is in a separate output group and have it write machine parseable data there in addition to human readable data on stdout.

I can then find all of these files and parse the data in them in downstream tools.

Is there any prior work on this, or does everything just try to parse the human readable output?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend running the error checkers as extra actions.

I don't think Bazel currently has hooks for custom error handlers like you describe. Please consider opening a feature request: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/new

Comment: Update: see the [email thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bazel-discuss/cIBIP-Oyzzw/caesbhdEAAAJ) where the discussion continued.